# Question about a group-theoretic Chinese remainder theorem and intersections of normal finite-index subgroups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, chinese-remainder-theorem, infinite-groups

I have recently been wondering about the group-theoretic Chinese remainder theorem. In particular, I was wondering whether this analogue can be generated to the case of more than two subgroups:

[Showing that $G/(H\cap K)\cong (G/H)\times (G/K)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254448/showing-that-g-h-cap-k-cong-g-h-times-g-k)

An answer to following question demonstrates that it cannot, by giving an example where $G=(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2$:

[Validation for a conjecture about Chinese Remainder Theorem for groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954401/validation-for-a-conjecture-about-chinese-remainder-theorem-for-groups?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However, I was wondering whether anyone had a counterexample to this in an infinite group where we restrict the normal subgroups to having finite index. In particular, what I would like is an example of an infinite group $G$ and normal subgroups $L,M,N\triangleleft G$ all having finite index and satisfying $LM=LN=MN=G$ but $L(M\cap N)\neq G$ (or a proof that no such thing is possible). Can something be said of groups in which this cannot occur (e.g. $\mathbb Z$)?

Compare also the following question, in which it is shown that the Chinese remainder theorem still works if we take the indices to be coprime:

[An Analogue of Chinese Remainder Theorem for Groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635743/an-analogue-of-chinese-remainder-theorem-for-groups)

Comment: Just take your counterexample with $G$ finite, and take the direct product of all groups/subgroups with a fixed infinite group.

Comment: You have an example with the Klein $4$-group, so just find an infinite group that projects onto the Klein $4$-group and lift the examples.

Comment: One way to do this is what YCor suggest; e.g., $C_2\times C_2\times \mathbb{Z}$, and take your subgroups to be $C_2\times\{e\}\times \mathbb{Z}$, $\{e\}\times C_2\times \mathbb{Z}$, and $\langle (x,x)\rangle\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. Another is to take $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, and take the relevant overgroups of $2\mathbb{Z}\times 2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks all three for your great responses!